# How can I change fractions as tick labels with real numbers?

Tags: gui-construction, ticks

When using HorizontalGauge or VerticalGauge the scale divisions are frequently labels with fractions (1/5, 2/5) etc., which looks terrible and is hard to read. I have not found a way to force labels into real numbers e.g. 0.2, 0.4 etc.

This should be simple but none of the options seem to allow it?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. I have not been able to find an example in the docs with fractions on display. I would like to see a minimal working example.

Comment: Like @Syed, I was surprised too.  Here is a work-around: `HorizontalGauge[Range[10]/10] /. Rational[n_, d_] :> N[n/d]`   @Jan, it is good idea to post a little code showing what you've tried--that way you will get more specific advice.

Comment: I had the issue on pretty much every attempt with these gauges on small intervals, e.g. HorizontalGauge[0.3, {0, 2}]. Your work-around seems to do the trick. Thank you! Will greatly improve the demos I have using this code.

Comment: I am on v12.2.0 Win7-x64 and I don't see fractions. Which version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: Welcome Jan! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). show due diligence, [edit] the question if it can be improved, like when adding new information, use the comments only for comments. give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: @Syed I'm using v13 on both MacOS and Windows and the problem with the fraction ticks appeared on both.